# Creating a very detailed report using Excel and/or Access

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

I have a database/spreadsheet of information that I need to make a very detailed report from. My knowledge on Access is quite limited so I started doing a mock up of the Report layout in Excel and made this:[image]

So from there, I need the information from the data base to be placed in the properly labeled cells. There are over 2500+ entries in the spreadsheet/database, so if creating a report that looks pretty spot on to the one above in access is doable, that might be an easier route.

Comment: admittedly i can not see the image at work (network filtering) but have you tried using Microsoft Word and the Mail Merge feature?

Comment: Do you have a database or a spreadsheet?

Comment: Comment by @kdicus: Have you ever done any database work? I guess, here's what I'm asking -- what is your technical ability with respect to the following: Excel, Access, VBA, ODBC? On a scale from 1 to 10, how would you rate your ability on each of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go straight from database to report, have a look at [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/index.php?q=project/ireport) - which is a bit like [Crystal report](http://crystalreports.com/)s without the cost and can connect to Access via ODBC ([forum post](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=73202)). Admittedly, this will require some learning and may not be a way you want to go, but iReport is a very flexible tool

Comment: Is it easier to use than the Access report designer?

Answer (score 0):

A couple books on the subject you might want to check out:

- [Excel 2007 Advanced Report Development](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470046449) by Timothy Zapawa, published Wiley
- [The Excel Analyst's Guide to Access](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470567015) by Michael Alexander, also published by Wiley

The former should have plenty of tips on formatting your data and placing it in the proper locations, the latter will give you an introduction to the features of Access you need to get your data into Excel.